# Would humans, and animals be able to survive on this planet?

Tags: planets, fauna, atmosphere, habitability

My question is pretty simple, all the details about the planet are pictured below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is too much CO2, humans would die.

Comment: Please, put relevant info as text, to make your question readable, and accessible for search engines.

Comment: All of the "relevant info" is provided in those two pictures.

Comment: Not everybody can view the pictures though.

Comment: @Bellerophon is right. On mobile site that's nightmare. Also, search on site can't access that info, so no one with similar question will be able to find it.

Comment: The SO2 content is a worry too. Major respiratory problems & possible death for terrestrial humans. The simple answer may be no. Environment suits will be mandatory for humans & animals.

Answer (score 3):

No humans can't survive. The atmosphere has 43% carbon dioxide and humans die at around 10% carbon dioxide so there is no way they can survive.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take this one attribute at a time -

O2 - 54%: At this level, almost any organic material will burn explosively.

CO2 - 45%: This is about 5 times the toxic level for humans, so that's probably out.

SO2 - 1.2%: Since no country allows worker exposure (long term) of even 1 ppm (.0001%), and about 20 ppm (.002%) is lethal for long exposure, this atmosphere is guaranteed to kill almost all known life forms. And let's not forget the omnipresent acid rain, caused by the combination of SO2 and water. Lots of acid rain.

Atmospheric pressure - 0.115 atm: This is the pressure at about 50,000 feet. Even with the higher oxygen levels, humans cannot function at this pressure. And, obviously, birds can't fly, since the low air density means their wings cannot provide enough lift. The only "good" part of this is that the fire hazard is probably not a problem, since the total amount of oxygen available to a fire is almost too low to support combustion - although I'm not certain of this.

So, pretty much across the board, your planet cannot support life outside the ocean. And the life in the ocean must be pretty vigorous to support the oxygen fraction, especially in light of the SO2 levels, which imply an enormous level of volcanic activity. The SO2 will constantly be combining with water vapor and washing out of the atmosphere. On earth, the half-life of SO2 in the atmosphere is about 6 to 24 hours, although this would obviously increase under high concentrations due to lack of sufficient water vapor to combine with it. But the high replacement rates suggest that the oceans will become very strongly acid within centuries to millenia, and how such an ocean is going to keep producing free oxygen is not remotely obvious.

Comment: Are you sure even at the reduced pressure the O2 and CO2 is still toxic? I understand why the SO2 is toxic. But I still think it might be possible to have animal life exist on the planet as long as it evolved there, they would be adapted to the harsh conditions .

Answer (score 0):

Humans, in there current form, would die.

Animals... most surface animals would die. Probably only bacteria and fauna could survive those conditions... but 1 lightning strike would probably ignite the entire atmosphere (53.5% O2!)...

For marine life, They would have the water to buffer them from the atmosphere, and deep sea colonies that survive around ocean vents would probably be ok. With the time it would take the atmosphere to defuse down to them, they could easily evolve to adapt to the change.

Now life in a more generic sense would probably be able to evolve to thrive (ignoring the part when the planet explodes because O2) since processing O2 and CO2 is the most efficient form of energy storage we know. Fauna would probably evolve to be fire resistant, and life would probably swell, explode, drop to a few survivors, then swell up till the next major atmosphere burn. =P